# Does the rollback transactions feature only work when an exception is thrown?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, struts

I have this declaration above my class declaration. Will spring only rollback when DAOException is thrown?

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { ManagerException.class, DAOException.class })
```

If that is the case, how can I rollback a bad commit without throwing an exception. Currently my database package functions return an error message, I want to roll back and still display the error message to the user without throwing an exception and crashing the app.

Comment: you can do it whenever you want

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-declarative-rolling-back) says:

> You can also indicate a required rollback programmatically. Although very simple, this process is quite invasive, and tightly couples your code to the Spring Framework's transaction infrastructure:

```
public void resolvePosition() {
    try {
        // some business logic...
    } catch (NoProductInStockException ex) {
        // trigger rollback programmatically
        TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
    }
}
```